# mongo query which costs different time from java code and shell

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo query which costs different time from java code and shell.
Java code is below,

*The version of mongo server is v2.6.5 , and version v2.4.8 doesn't have the question.*

```
DBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.put("accountId",accountId);
List<DBObject> listOr = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
listOr.add(new BasicDBObject("status", 11));
listOr.add(new BasicDBObject("status", 12));
obj.put("$or", listOr);
BasicDBObject andDB = new BasicDBObject();
andDB.append("$gt", 0);
andDB.append("$lt",4514185);
obj.put("currBoardId",andDB);
DBCursor cur = null;
cur = coll.find(obj,new BasicDBObject("currBoardId",1)).sort(new BasicDBObject("commentId",-1)).limit(10);
```

when I run the code, I can get slow query record from profile collection. It shows "nscanned" : 1566031  and  "millis" : 4724 .

```
> db.system.profile.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(10);
```

> { "op" : "query", "ns" : "l_comment.comment", "query" : { "$query" : { "accountId" : NumberLong(4), "$or" : [  {  "status" : 11 },  {  "status" : 12 } ], "currBoardId" : { "$gt" : 0, "$lt" : NumberLong(4514185) } }, "$orderby" : { "commentId" : -1 } }, "cursorid" : 220355902849, "ntoreturn" : 10, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 1566031, "nscannedObjects" : 1566031, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 5, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(8921271), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(14), "w" : NumberLong(2) } }, "nreturned" : 10, "responseLength" : 410, "millis" : 4724, "execStats" : { "type" : "PROJECTION", "works" : 1566031, "yields" : 12234, "unyields" : 12234, "invalidates" : 0, "advanced" : 10, "needTime" : 0, "needFetch" : 0, "isEOF" : 0, "children" : [     {   "type" : "FETCH",   "works" : 1566031,  "yields" : 12234,   "unyields" : 12234,     "invalidates" : 0,  "advanced" : 10,    "needTime" : 1566021,   "needFetch" : 0,    "isEOF" : 0,    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,    "forcedFetches" : 0,    "matchTested" : 10,     "children" : [  {   "type" : "IXSCAN",  "works" : 1566031,  "yields" : 12234,   "unyields" : 12234,     "invalidates" : 0,  "advanced" : 1566031,   "needTime" : 0,     "needFetch" : 0,    "isEOF" : 0,    "keyPattern" : "{ commentId: -1.0 }",   "isMultiKey" : 0,   "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['commentId']: [MaxKey, MinKey]",    "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,     "dupsTested" : 0,   "dupsDropped" : 0,  "seenInvalidated" : 0,  "matchTested" : 0,  "keysExamined" : 1566031,   "children" : [ ] } ] } ] }, "ts" : ISODate("2015-02-10T08:51:16.195Z"), "client" : "192.168.66.103", "allUsers" : [ ], "user" : "" }

But when I run the query from shell, it returns fast.

```
db.comment.find({ "accountId" : NumberLong(4), "$or" : [  {  "status" : 11 },  {  "status" : 12 } ], "currBoardId" : { "$gt" : 0, "$lt" : NumberLong(4514185) }}).sort({commentId:-1}).limit(10)
```

below is the output of it's explain. It shows the query scans 10517 records and use 109 millis.
Why this happened, how can I improve the code?

Thanks for any tips and help.

```
{
    "clauses" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor idx_atst",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 10,
            "nscannedObjects" : 10517,
            "nscanned" : 10517,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "accountId" : [
                    [
                        NumberLong(4),
                        NumberLong(4)
                    ]
                ],
                "rootId" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "status" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "type" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 0,
            "nscanned" : 0,
            "scanAndOrder" : true,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "accountId" : [
                    [
                        NumberLong(4),
                        NumberLong(4)
                    ]
                ],
                "rootId" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "status" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "type" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
    "n" : 10,
    "nscannedObjects" : 10517,
    "nscanned" : 10517,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 31574,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 31574,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "nYields" : 246,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 109,
    "server" : "app-sz-2-3.sz.chosk.net:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "works" : 10529,
        "yields" : 246,
        "unyields" : 246,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 10,
        "needTime" : 10519,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 0,
        "children" : [
            {
                "type" : "OR",
                "works" : 10529,
                "yields" : 246,
                "unyields" : 246,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "advanced" : 10,
                "needTime" : 10519,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "dupsTested" : 10,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "locsForgotten" : 0,
                "matchTested_0" : 0,
                "matchTested_1" : 0,
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "SORT",
                        "works" : 10529,
                        "yields" : 246,
                        "unyields" : 246,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 10,
                        "needTime" : 10518,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "forcedFetches" : 0,
                        "memUsage" : 4675,
                        "memLimit" : 33554432,
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "type" : "FETCH",
                                "works" : 10518,
                                "yields" : 246,
                                "unyields" : 246,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 1909,
                                "needTime" : 8608,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                                "matchTested" : 1909,
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "works" : 10518,
                                        "yields" : 246,
                                        "unyields" : 246,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "advanced" : 10517,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needFetch" : 0,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "keyPattern" : "{ accountId: 1, rootId: -1.0, status: 1, type: 1 }",
                                        "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['accountId']: [4, 4], field #1['rootId']: [MaxKey, MinKey], field #2['status']: [MinKey, MaxKey], field #3['type']: [MinKey, MaxKey]",
                                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                        "matchTested" : 0,
                                        "keysExamined" : 10517,
                                        "children" : [ ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type" : "SORT",
                        "works" : 0,
                        "yields" : 246,
                        "unyields" : 246,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "advanced" : 0,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needFetch" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 0,
                        "forcedFetches" : 0,
                        "memUsage" : 0,
                        "memLimit" : 33554432,
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "type" : "FETCH",
                                "works" : 0,
                                "yields" : 246,
                                "unyields" : 246,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "advanced" : 0,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needFetch" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 0,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "forcedFetches" : 0,
                                "matchTested" : 0,
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "type" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "works" : 0,
                                        "yields" : 246,
                                        "unyields" : 246,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "advanced" : 0,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needFetch" : 0,
                                        "isEOF" : 0,
                                        "keyPattern" : "{}",
                                        "isMultiKey" : 0,
                                        "boundsVerbose" : "field #0['accountId']: [4, 4], field #1['rootId']: [MaxKey, MinKey], field #2['status']: [MinKey, MaxKey], field #3['type']: [MinKey, MaxKey]",
                                        "yieldMovedCursor" : 0,
                                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                                        "matchTested" : 0,
                                        "keysExamined" : 0,
                                        "children" : [ ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: the difference in the query is, that you restrict the returned key in you Java code with `new BasicDBObject("currBoardId",1)` stripping the results should take some time but should not change the scanned Objects. Interesting.

Comment: This is what confused me

Comment: can you show the definition of variable `accountId` in java please.

Comment: all the parameters are in the slow query record,  I run the query copied from there in the shell.

Comment: The query run from Java and the query run from the shell used different indexes. The query run from Java used an index to handle the sort `{ "commentId" : -1 }` while the query run from the shell used an index to handle the actual query predicate. This explains why the `nscanned` for the Java query was much higher than for the shell query. Does this choice of index happen every time? Or is the Java query choosing the sort index only some of the time? Do you need the sort index for something else? Could you add the sort field to the shell query's index?

Comment: The difference of  `nscanned` happened every time. And query from shell also used sort by `commentId`.  But if they used different index, can this be treated as a bug? The version of mongo server is v2.6.5 , and version v2.4.8 doesn't have the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the hint of  wdberkeley , I paid some attention to the indexes. I am not understand how mongodb choose the index, but after I add another index, the query from java code choose the right index. Even if I drop the index which added later, it still use the right index. So if the query didnot use the index we want, we should use hint to assign the index which we want.

The index I added:

```
ensureIndex({"accountId" : -1,"type" : 1,"status" : 1},{"name" : "idx_ats"});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Shell-query you are using `NumberLong(4514185)` in your `$lt` in your `$or` statement. But in your Java query you are using `andDB.append("$lt", 4514185);` This is a `Integer` so your Java query needs a type cast from Integer to Long. Try to use `andDB.append("$lt", 4514185L);` with an `L` after your number to create the query with a Long. `accountId` should also be a `Long`.

Comment: In my code, the parameter type is Long , I just wrote them in direct number to show  the example.